# How to add a JNI C function, accessible as a java method, into my android application?

Tags: java, android, c, android-studio, java-native-interface

I want to know how to(from android-studio or by modifying the build files), add a C/C++ file with a function that shows up as a java accessible method.

Comment: This is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code).

Comment: I forgot to remove my question, not going to lie.